# Keeping Interfaces Separate

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my C# app I have several libraries.  E.g:

- main app EXE

  - Helper DLL, A
  - Helper DLL, B
  - Helper DLL, C
  - Data access DLL, D

My data access DLL, D, has an interface it exposes.  Helper DLL B exposes another interface that has basically the same properties, but it's not the same interface (namespace wise and slightly with respect to how those properties are accessed).  Furthermore, Helper DLL A uses what B and D expose.  This is leading to confusion on my part as I need to connect B & D in A, but I find myself trying to convert between these interfaces and something doesn't seem right about it.

I'm confused as to what I should do:

1. Use the data access interface from D across the whole app or...
2. Have each DLL have separate interfaces and convert between them as they cross from one DLL to another.

Is there a preferred solution?  If so, why?

Comment: What do you have to maintain/compile when you keep the interfaces in a separate assembly? If you change on interface, how many assemblies do you have to update? This brings you to a good point: How responsible are the assemblies designed, are they really **contracts** or just loose wireups?

Comment: You make a good point.  It's more so that they were responsibly designed and working, but I went to refactor them and I haven't been as responsible this time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all that interfaces, it's diffcult to say to me just by reading your post, I would, personaly, suggest put them all in DataAccess and also conversion utilities too. So you will have all in one place and any Helper you'll write in the future will need to refer only that.

Comment: No, it's good design for them to specify the interfaces in each assembly that needs them - it's a good way to provide separation by improving abstraction. I do wonder, however, that the OP is confusing an 'Interface', that only specifies the, well, interface, with an actual implementation of that interface. Perhaps he is indeed not referring to interfaces at all, which would be inconvenient.

Comment: It depends on your architecture, it's not really clear from post how he would like to envolve in the future. Maintaining one interface per assembly can create a lot of different interfaces all arround project and create a confusion after 1 year of development. I repeat, it depends on project.

Comment: I normally maintain one interface per /class/.  For example, each assembly could contain an ILogger, such that Main.exe only has to provide one class that inherts from each ILogger. This means that each assembly does not need to depend on the others.

Comment: If you're talking about plugins I would agree that having each plugin "detached" from others is waht we want.  For other cases I don't really see a problem in creating dependences between different assemblies of your project. The right choice is up to Architect.

Comment: I would have to agree with that, in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? Can't you just make a class in main implement those interfaces as necessary?

Classes can inherit from more than one interface, or you can define various proxies that inherit from their respective class that operate on some common object instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another DLL with the interfaces that you want to use across the other three DLLs. Then any object that implements one of these interfaces will be able to be handled the same no matter of which DLL it was declared in.
You can also extend any of these interfaces in one of the DLLS to include extra properties or methods where required.